# How to limit the -findall curl call result to certain number in FileMaker's curl call

Tags: filemaker

I know the -findall curl call parameter for FileMaker server will return all the rows in that specific database, however, for testing purpose, I just want to show for maybe, three.

I am aware sql has command of LIMIT, but how a curl command for FM is handling this same scenario?

In this case, -find is not an option for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using curl to query a FileMaker server.  If so, you are looking for the -max url parameter

From the [Help PDF for FileMaker Server 13](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/13/en/fms13_cwp_xml.pdf)

**–max (Maximum records) query parameter**
Specifies the maximum number of records you want returned
Value is: A number, or use the value all to return all records. If –max is not specified, all records
are returned.